# Extrapulate the height for every point of a grid from a random list

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, math

I have an ordered grid list of points with x,y values associated, I want to extrapolate the height for every point from another list of points that have x,y and **z** associated.
At the moment what I do it's this:

```
    private Vector3[][] UpdatePointHeight(Vector3[][] points, List<double[]> randomPointsList)
{
    Vector3 p;
    for (int j = 0; j < points.Length; j++)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < points[j].Length; i++)
        {
            p = points[j][i];
            float midDist = float.MaxValue;
            for (int k = 0; k < randomPointsList.Count; k++)
            {
                double[] ph = randomPointsList[k];
                Vector3 ph3 = new Vector3((float)ph[1], (float)ph[0], 0);
                float distance = Vector3.Distance(p, ph3);
                if (midDist > distance)
                {
                    midDist = distance;
                    p.z = (float)ph[2];
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return points;
}
```

What can I do to improve this operation?

Comment: I don't know what you're asking.

Comment: I have a series of random points that represent heights on a 3d space, I want to create a regular elevation grid from them.

Comment: Cool you have some points and some code. What's your question? Does your code do what you want it to? If so, what's the issue you want to solve?

Comment: Are you sure you don't mean "interpolate"?

Comment: The issue is about the performance, in this way if there are too many points in the random list this code becomes very slow, is there any way to improve it with some mathematical or some sort technique?